# Can't access a disposed object

Tags: vb.net

I'm doing an asynchronous sub-routine to keep on listening to UDP client. When I received the message, I will update the UI thread by using BeginInvoke. But now, I'm facing an issue when I reopen the form. It'll throw me an exception - Can't access a disposed object. Object name: checkInOut. checkInOut is my form name.

```
Private Sub checkInOut_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        FormSettings()
        udpClient.BeginReceive(AddressOf udpAsyncReceive, Nothing)
End Sub

Private Sub udpAsyncReceive(asyncResult As IAsyncResult)
    Try
        Dim remoteIpEndPoint As New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0)
        Dim receiveBytes As Byte() = udpClient.EndReceive(asyncResult, remoteIpEndPoint)
        Dim receiveMsg As String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(receiveBytes)
        If Me.IsHandleCreated = False Then
            Me.CreateHandle()
        End If
        '' Pass the string to a method that runs on the UI thread
        Me.BeginInvoke(New Action(Of String)(AddressOf DataReceived), receiveMsg)
        '' Continue receiving
        udpClient.BeginReceive(AddressOf udpAsyncReceive, Nothing)
    Catch ex As Exception
        GeneralHelper.showExceptionErrorMsg(ex)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub DataReceived(receiveMsg As String)
    txtReservationID.Text = receiveMsg
End Sub
```

I'm using a menu strip to call the openForm() and re-open the form.

```
Private Sub CheckInOutToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckInOutToolStripMenuItem.Click
    GeneralHelper.openForm(New checkInOut)
End Sub
```

openForm sub-routine

```
Public Sub openForm(ByVal formName As Form)

    If Form.ActiveForm.MdiChildren.Length > 0 Then
        For Each childForm In Form.ActiveForm.MdiChildren
            childForm.Close()
        Next
    End If

    formName.MdiParent = Form.ActiveForm
    formName.Show()
End Sub
```

I'm looking forward for the solution. Thank you.

Comment: Can you show us the code you use to reopen the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like at some point you executed `checkInOut.Close` at some point and later on in your code you tried to re-open it.

The `.close` method closes the form and marks it for disposal. If you want to carry on using a form instead of

```
checkInOut.Close
```

use

```
checkInOut.Hide
```